# SQL ServerでOracleのsqlplusやstartコマンドのようなことはできますか？

Tags: sql-server, oracle

sqlcmdというものがあるそうですが、このコマンドでSQL Serverに接続した後、
データベースを作成したり、テーブルを作成するスクリプトを
実行したいと考えております。

Comment: sqlcmd はどのように知りましたか？また、「sqlcmd」でgoogle検索すると公式のマニュアルがヒットしますが、これらはご覧になりましたか？

Comment: [こちら](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)はどうですかSQLserveなら利用出来ると思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlcmd` でクエリを発行すれば、データベースやテーブルの作成が可能です。

```
sqlcmd -U ユーザー名 -P パスワード -S サーバー名 -Q "create database SampleDb01 on primary (name=dat1,filename='C:\temp\SampleDb01.mdf',size=10MB,filegrowth=10) log on (name=log1,filename='C:\temp\SampleDb01.ldf',size=10MB,filegrowth=10);"
```

Oracle の start コマンドと完全に一致するものは SQL Server には無いと思いますが、Windowsにおけるサービスの起動でしたら `net` や `sc` が使用できます。

```
sc start MSSQLSERVER
```

---

[sqlcmd ユーティリティ - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
[CREATE DATABASE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
[CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)